# Make the whole form as readonly in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my Anuglarjs 1.5 application I have a lot of pages with a form in them.

I wanted to adopt some mechanism to make some forms disabled, and when I googled about it, I found that encapsulating the form element with a fieldset and make it disabled will do the trick. when I test it it worked, but only inputs and buttons were disabled and not clickable elements like (divs, spans, icons...).

So what I decided to do, is to create some function that will add a fieldset and set it disabled whenever I met the condition to make my form elements readonly, but I don't know how can I access to the form direcive so I can create a post link function to execute that function.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: you could play with CSS and simply disable a cursor: make a directive with `element.css({cursor: "not-allowed"});`. Then any element with your directive name will be [not-clickable, i.e. "read only"](https://wwija.com/computer-internet-technology/52429_disabling-a-div-in-angularjs-using-ng-disabled.html)

Comment: <fieldset ng-disabled="editable"> /*wrap all the input fields here*/ </fieldset>     $scope.editable=true; in controller before http call and make it false after it called. I'm using this approach in my code.Hope it will solves yours as well.

Comment: @KishorVelayutham The problem is that I can't wrap the input fields, What I have to do is to adopt a mechanism where I only access to the post link function for the form directive and there I'll call a function which will do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

You can't make the whole form readonly or disabled. You need to make individual inputs readonly or disabled.

You can use a form element and use [ng-readonly attribute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngReadonly) or [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)

Here is a working example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl">
  <form>
    Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstname">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Disabled Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstname" ng-disabled="true">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Readonly Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstname" ng-readonly="true">
  </form>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstname = "John";
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

If you can't use the above method and want to disable every form, then you could use the below code. **You can replace the "disabled" attribute with "readonly"**.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="formCtrl">
  <form name="form1">
    First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstname">
    <br/>
    First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstname">
    <br/>
    First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstname">
    <br/>
  </form>
  <form name="form2">
  <input type="text" ng-model="firstname">
  <textarea type="text" ng-model="firstname">
  </textarea>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstname = "John";
    
    angular.forEach(document.forms,(f)=>{
       angular.forEach(f.children,(i)=>{
          i.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
       });
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As I said I have a lot of forms in my application and I can't just go for each one and add an `ng-readonly` to it's elements, I want to adapt a mechanism where I only access to the post link function for the form directive and there I'll call a function which will do the trick.

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki I have updated my answer to include what you want. Take a look.

Comment: Sorry but my question is not about how to make the form readonly from the form's controller code like I said I want a single code that would be applied on all forms, normally this will be in the directive and not in the controller.

Comment: I have given you the code to make all forms in current document readonly. You can move that code to your directive. You can replace f.children with element.children. Assuming you directive is applied on form.

Comment: I don't think you understood, my problem is that I don't know the directive responsible for the forms in my application, angularjs has a built-in directive which controlls the form, what I want is how to access to that directive and add my code to it, without changing in the directive itself.

Comment: You cant do that. You can't change the angular directives.